# How to reset chrome inspector?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

Something is wrong with my Chrome inspector, I would like to reset the Chrome inspector to out of the box settings. How could I do ? (wihout removing my whole Chrome)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Find the following two files and delete them. These files contain the settings for the inspector.

```
chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage
chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage-journal
```

Please make sure to restart the Chrome again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I'am trying it. Will see in 5 mins !

Comment: what OS are you using? just curious. Also, see http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory

Comment: You can find the file locations by going to chrome://version/ and opening the profile folder noted there -- as shown in this answer: http://superuser.com/a/905304/10429

Comment: For Windows 8.1: the folder is: [UserFolder]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage

Answer (score 75):

1. Open **DevTools** by pressing **F12** or **ctrl + shift + i**
2. press **F1** or click on ... on the top right corner beside cross to open settings
3. scroll at the bottom or to the right of screen and press **[restore defaults and reload]** button
4. Restart chrome

NOTE: **relaunch chrome is very much necessary**

done !

Comment: Note: this also resets _all_ of your Devtool preferences, including custom UA overrides, etc

Comment: It helped me, but I didn't have to restart chrome

Comment: I didn't have to restart either.  I guess things have likely come a long way since 2017.  It's probably worth editing the answer.

Comment: Clicking on ... doesn't work there is settings icon next to it.

Answer (score 11):

Looks like in today's Chrome, there is a "Restore defaults and reload" button under `Developer Tools => Preferences`, which will work.

Comment: Menu Item "Customize and Control DevTools" 
=> Settings 
=> Preferences

or press F1 key while in DevTools

Comment: This method doesn't work. Guess restart is the only way.. mine crashed when I ran an infinite `for of` loop

Answer (score 4):

On a Mac running 10.9.2:

```
 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local\ Storage
```

Or

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome\ Canary/Default/Local\ Storage/
```

Remove

- chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage
- chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage-journal

Answer (score 0):

Thought I needed to remove chrome dev tools on a windows 10 machine.   I was debugging and looking at sources of files , bootstrap in particular and the developer tools locked up.   I was looking through all the chrome user data but then I ended up fixing it by

`Open up chrome by itself , then open dev tools and clear the console and then navigate to elements, then I opened the localhost page I was constantly getting frozen on and then it worked.`

True it is not necessarily "fixed" but it beats spending hours with no reward.