# Clear profile data for chrome dev tools only (to solve problems with Javascript sources not shown)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to reset the chrome dev tools, without resetting the full profile?

I have the problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32566621/288568

And I am wondering if there is a more selective fix, without loosing bookmarks, history and so on.

I tried

[How to reset chrome inspector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911066/how-to-reset-chrome-inspector)

And

```
cd Local Storage
rm *theSiteAffected*
```

which did not help

Comment: File a bug report please. https://crbug.com This certainly shouldn't be happening and if it is common then the issue should get internal triage to figure out what is going on.