# How could I reset all changes on developer mode

Tags: css

I'm using Chrome to develop CSS on my project.
However, I found if I toogled/changed some options.
It won't be reset even the page is reloaded.
That's I will suffer the un-freshed style then.

eg: as you can see the overflow-y has been `unchecked`. It will keep as unchecked status even I reload the page.

How could I reset all changes in my case?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you try clearing your cache?

Comment: it doesn't work for my case. That's for sure :)

Comment: Try the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911066/how-to-reset-chrome-inspector . Tell me if it helped